# Same zone for S3 Express One Zone and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When creating an S3 Express One Zone bucket (i.e. the new Directory bucket type), it asks me to select the availability zone. The instructions say:

> For optimal performance, choose an Availability Zone local to your compute services. The Availability Zone can’t be changed after the bucket is created.

Since I am going to access the bucket from an AWS Lambda function, I understand the above instructions to mean that my Lambda function should run in the same availability zone. However, there is no option to choose a zone when creating a Lambda function. In what way can I follow the above advice for achieving optimal performance?

P.S. The [question at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUuuOUZ_sGTFiZ7IXcwR6a3g/same-zone-for-s3-express-one-zone-and-lambda)

Comment: **Side-note:** A _S3 Express One Zone_ bucket is designed for high volume situations like running Spark clusters or doing AI/ML against data in S3. It isn't really relevant for data being accessed by Lambda functions. It costs more for storage, too.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein To handle a user request, I need to read 5,000 objects from S3 in under one second. Currently I invoke 50 Lambda instances in parallel, each of which fetches 100 objects using asynchronous I/O. I hope that with S3 Express 1Z, each Lambda will be able to handle more objects and less Lambda instances will be required. Am I not thinking about S3 Express 1Z correctly?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have studied the performance of the new bucket type vs. the standard in AWS Lambda and reported the results [in re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUlDN0BEuhR4eb0HhzL9yhuQ/lambda-network-bottleneck-reading-objects-in-parallel-from-s3-express-one-zone-and-from-s3-standard-is-same-speed).

Comment: Interesting! You could try the same test from a mid-size EC2 instance (eg m6) to see whether the network was a bottleneck. It would also be worth testing with larger data volumes, which is what S3 Express is meant to address. There would be overhead 'per object', so larger objects would have higher performance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein "to see whether the network was a bottleneck". What other candidate can you think of?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions run best if they are *not* connected to a VPC. In such a case, there is no concept of an Availability Zone. (Behind the scenes it will run in a single AZ, but that information is not exposed.)

You can optionally connect a Lambda function to a VPC, in which case **you would specify the subnets to use**. Each subnet is associated with a single Availability Zone.

However, please note that if a Lambda function is connected to a VPC and it wants to communicate with S3, then it would either need a NAT Gateway (extra charges apply) or a **VPC Endpoint for S3**.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-express-networking.html#s3-express-networking-vpc-gateway) walks one though creating an endpoint before it tells one how to create a bucket, so I did exactly that. However, it is not clear how the endpoint and the bucket are related, since there is no mention of the endpoint when creating the bucket...

Comment: A traditional VPC Endpoint modifies routing within the VPC. It works automatically without needing to be specifically referenced by the bucket. This 'Express' stuff is rather new so I haven't played with it. That documentation mentions the need for Regional endpoints for bucket management and Zonal endpoints for accessing objects. You might need both types depending upon your usage. The fact that they now have a zone-level endpoints for Express means you should definitely connect your Lambda function to a subnet in the matching AZ. Let us know how you go!

Comment: For now, I am stuck not being able to access my bucket, neither [from Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77612945/2725810) nor [from CLI](https://repost.aws/questions/QUsv_Z3DfBQ3629L3c2_3KKQ/latest-aws-cli-does-not-see-s3-express-one-zone-buckets). If you have a clue about what's going on, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: If you disconnect the Lambda function from the VPC, does it work? Presumably it would. In this case, it's a matter of figuring out the VPC Endpoints for S3 Express, but you might also want to check the Security Group attached to the Lambda function. I haven't played with S3 Express, nor its endpoint, so don't have experience to offer on that topic.

Comment: The function is not connected to a VPC and I deleted the endpoint. It still is not working. `aws s3api list-directory-buckets` works from CLI though.

Comment: Adding a layer with the latest `boto3` did the trick.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it! Feel free to create your own Answer so that future readers can learn from your experience, especially since S3 Express is so new.