# S3 Express One Zone: no such bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sdk

I created a directory-type bucket at S3 Express One Zone and am trying to get an object from it from a AWS Lambda function. Both are in the same `us-east-1` region. My function is based on the example from the [documentation][1]:

```py
import boto3
import json

def get_object(s3_client, bucket_name, key_name):
    try:
        response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
        body = response['Body'].read()
        print(f"Got object '{key_name}' from bucket '{bucket_name}'.")
        return body
    except:
        print(f"Couldn't get object '{key_name}' from bucket '{bucket_name}'.")
        raise

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    resp = get_object(s3_client, 'mybucket--use1-az4--x-s3', 'myobject')
    return {'statusCode': 200}
```

I get an exception at calling `get_object`:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist.
```

If I use the name of a regular (non-directory) bucket, it works. So it is not a permissions problem.

I thought that may be I am using the version of `boto3` that does not support the new bucket type. So, I created the Lambda function anew (Python 3.10 environment), but still get the same result.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** Adding a layer with the latest `boto3` resolved the issue.

Comment: I think AWS has not provided support for these new _directory-type_ buckets yet. I tried running `aws s3 ls` and it only returned _general-purpose_ buckets.

Comment: @ArpitJain I recall seeing that it requires a certain version of `aws`. I am sure they would say so in the documentation if it was not available.

Comment: @ArpitJain They [announced general availability](https://press.aboutamazon.com/2023/11/aws-announces-the-general-availability-of-amazon-s3-express-one-zone) on November the 28th.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my aws php SDK and can list buckets and get objects from the directory buckets.

Comment: Just also tried boto3 and was able to get the object.
`arpit@in-arpitjain-P14s:~/projects$ python3 index.py
Got object 'sample.jfif' from bucket 'dev-arpit--use1-az4--x-s3'.`

Comment: Can you please verify the bucket name in the error message? In your code, if the bucket does not exist, it also throws the exception: `Couldn't get object '{key_name}' from bucket '{bucket_name}'.`

Comment: @ArpitJain Yes, that's what it throws. I updated my own CLI (it is now 2.14.5), but `aws s3 ls` does not list my directory bucket either!.. (it does list the regular buckets)

Comment: On my local dev environment, I'm able to list directory buckets and also get object from boto3. But with AWS lambda I can see the error.

Comment: @ArpitJain Thank you for corroborating! I [reported the issue at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU9eB_fQzoRa29kTvBtSHXew/bug-no-access-to-s3-express-one-zone-aka-directory-buckets-from-aws-lambda) and hope AWS team will notice it. I also updated the question to ask that whoever has a support plan reports the issue to the AWS team.